# CreateCompatibleDC() or DeleteDC() fail in continues loop in Python - possible memory leak?

Tags: python, memory-leaks, pywin32, win32gui, win32-process

I am feeding an opencv window in a loop with this specific window screen capture routine below.

**PROBLEM: after hundreds of cycles in the loop, it suddenly fail at either one of the two FAIL POINTS marked below in the code.**

I am suspecting possible memory leak, but if I am not mistaken, **I do delete and release** what's required as well as **I (re)select object before I delete** it.

(The reason I am using this method, because it is *important for me to be able to capture the specific window even if it is inactive and in the background* and I did not found any other module/method actually works.)

What am I overlooking?

```
import win32gui
import win32ui
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import cv2

while True:

        target_window = win32gui.FindWindow(None, ("Analytics dashboard - Google Chrome"))       
        
        hwndDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(target_window) 
        mfcDC  = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(hwndDC)  

        saveDC = mfcDC.CreateCompatibleDC()  #### <-- RANDOM FAIL POINT 1: win32ui.error: CreateCompatibleDC failed
                
        saveBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
        saveBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(mfcDC, screen_width, screen_height)
        saveDC.SelectObject(saveBitMap)    
        result = windll.user32.PrintWindow(target_window, saveDC.GetSafeHdc(), 3)
        bmpinfo = saveBitMap.GetInfo()
        bmpstr = saveBitMap.GetBitmapBits(True)
        
        screen_image = Image.frombuffer('RGB', (bmpinfo['bmWidth'], bmpinfo['bmHeight']), bmpstr, 'raw', 'BGRX', 0, 1)        

        mfcDC.DeleteDC()  #### <-- RANDOM FAIL POINT 2: win32ui.error: DeleteDC failed

        saveDC.DeleteDC()               
        win32gui.DeleteObject(saveBitMap.GetHandle())        
        win32gui.ReleaseDC(target_window, hwndDC) 

        image = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(screen_image), cv2.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR)
```

Comment: Make sure `target_window` is not `0`. Go to task manager and monitor "GDI usage" (it's not shown by default, you have to go to "Details", and select GDI. See if GDI objects are increasing. It's a problem if it goes above 1000 or 2000 handles.

Comment: @Barmak Shemirani : t hanks for your quick reply! Checked, target_window is never 0, always properly get it., also when it crash. I also checked GDI objects, and indeed increase as you indicated running the code above. The question why, since in my view I delete, release and selectobject properly. May I ask if you could grab the code and kindly test at your side to see it you could spot the trouble ?

Comment: I don't have `windll` and `cv2` extension, I commented those out and ran your code, couldn't see GDI leak. It doesn't go past 3. Maybe you have GDI leaks elsewhere.

Comment: @Barmak Shemirani : BIG thanks for your answer again. Following your comment, I did some extra test on myside too, and ow I can confirm, that CreateCompatibleDC or DeleteDC fails ONLY, when PrintWindow line is added. So, no we coudl narrow the problem to printwindow. I tried to research for any solution here, but I couldnt find anything. May i ask if you have any idea how to resolve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the above code with `ctypes.windll.user32.PrintWindow` and there were no GDI leaks. `PrintWindow`'s third argument should be `PW_CLIENTONLY` (1), or there is the undocumented `PW_RENDERFULLCONTENT` (2) option. Undocumented code is not reliable. I don't know what the constant (3) refers to.

If Chrome is the top window you should just take screen shot of desktop. This would be compliant.

It might help if you remove some of the code outside the loop, it will be more efficient at least.

```
import ctypes
import win32gui 
import win32ui
import win32con
from PIL import Image

hdesktop = win32gui.GetDesktopWindow()
(l, r, width, height) = win32gui.GetClientRect(hdesktop)
hdc = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hdesktop)
dc  = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(hdc)
memdc = dc.CreateCompatibleDC()
bitmap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
bitmap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(dc, width, height)
memdc.SelectObject(bitmap)

while True:
    hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow("Chrome_WidgetWin_1", None)
    if hwnd == 0:
        break
    result = ctypes.windll.user32.PrintWindow(hwnd, memdc.GetSafeHdc(), 2)
    if result == 1:
        bytes = bitmap.GetBitmapBits(True)
        img = Image.frombuffer('RGB', (width, height), bytes, 'raw', 'BGRX', 0, 1)
        img.save("file.bmp")
    #break
    
dc.DeleteDC()
memdc.DeleteDC()
win32gui.DeleteObject(bitmap.GetHandle())
win32gui.ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc)
```

You can also add `ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(2)` on top

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time. I fully understand your suggestions, but unfortunately, this gives black screen. Earlier, I ran into this issue with my code too, that's why I used the target window hwnd only, without getting desktop first, as well as the 3rd constant you mention MUST be 3 (though I don't know why) otherwise it always gives black screen for some reason. However, I try to adopt changes you suggested, and get back to you with the result.

Comment: Chrome will sometimes respond to `PW_RENDERFULLCONTENT ` (`2`), sometimes it doesn't. I think if you put `3` or `3000000`, the code will change it to `2`. A different program may change it `0` or return false. There is no standard for handling undocumented constants.

Comment: It took sometime, but I am happy to confirm, that your suggestion to move out from the loop the most part of the code, worked like charm ! BIG thank you for your time and help!! I accepted the answer and voted as well.